# Akka HTTP Streaming server kills connection after last message from queue

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a pretty simple app that consists of a Kafka consumer sitting behind an Akka HTTP streaming server. Upon receiving a request, the server starts up a new consumer for the specified user and begins reading messages from a queue:

```
def consumer(consumerGroup: String, from: Int) = {
  val topicsAndDate = Subscriptions.assignmentOffsetsForTimes(partitions.map(_ -> (System.currentTimeMillis() - from)): _*)

  Consumer.plainSource[String, GenericRecord](consumerSettings.withGroupId(consumerGroup), topicsAndDate)
    .map(record => record.timestamp() -> messageFormat.from(record.value()))
    .map {
      //convert to json
    }
}

def routes: Route = Route.seal(
  pathSingleSlash {
    complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "Say hello to akka-http"))
  } ~
  path("stream") {
    //some logic to validate user

    log.info("Received request from {} with 'from'={}", user, from)
    complete(consumer(user, from))  
  })

startServer("0.0.0.0", 8080)
```

The service works fine until the consumer has reached the latest message on the queue. Sixty seconds after this latest message has been returned, the connection to the server is killed every time. I want to keep the connection alive as the queue is populated with more messages every couple of minutes.

I have tried various different config options, but none seem to give the desired outcome. My current config looks like this:

```
akka {
  http {
    client {
      idle-timeout = 300s
    }
    server {
      idle-timeout = 600s
      linger-timeout = 15 min
    }
    host-connection-pool {
      max-retries = 30
      max-connections = 20
      max-open-requests = 32
      connecting-timeout = 60s
      client {
        idle-timeout = 300s
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried using the `server.websocket.periodic-keep-alive-max-idle = 1 second` setting, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Let me know if I need to supply any more relevant info.

Comment: Please clarify - which connection is closed? To kafka or from the http client?

Comment: Sounds like websockets + Alpakka Kafka adapter would be a good fit for your problem, there's even sample code on this: https://akka.io/alpakka-samples/kafka-to-websocket-clients/
As for the issue that you encounter, it may also be that the client is closing the connection. Perhaps it would help to inspect the network and request when it closes and see what happens on the protocol level.